# iPhone graphics: format for photo with transparency?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have some graphics I want to import into iPhone application. They are people / animals from photos that I cropped out that so they have transparent backgrounds. Obviously, I can't use JPEG as is traditionally recommended for photos because of transparency so what would be the second best option? I'm currently using png-24, but I assume that's too big. Is gif OK? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended by Apple to use PNG whenever possible. PNG is still a compressed format so I think you'll be fine with respect to size.

Comment: +1 Just about to say the same thing. I agree, PNG wherever possible!